# imap_search(); not working with Yahoo

Tags: php, imap, yahoo

I have a code, that searches few email boxes to check whether the email sent to that email account landed in inbox or spam. Here is the code:

```
// set the time the script can run to infinite.
set_time_limit (0);

// Require the connection file to the inboxes
require('conn.php');

// Temporry array with the clients
require('array.php');


// Begin Gmail Search
$gresult = array();
foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {
    $check = " ";
    $check = imap_search($gconnection1, 'FROM "'. $value . '"', SE_UID);
    if ($check) {
            $gresult["$key"] = 'v';
    } else {
        $check = " ";
        $check = imap_search($gconnection2, 'FROM "'. $value . '"', SE_UID);
        if ($check) {
            $gresult["$key"] = 'x';
        } else {
            $gresult["$key"] = 'nf';
        }
    }   
} // end of foreach loop  for Gmail Search


// Begin Outlook Search
$oresult = array();
foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {
    $check = " ";
    $check = imap_search($oconnection1, 'FROM "'. $value . '"', SE_UID);
    if ($check) {
            $oresult["$key"] = 'v';
    } else {
        $check = " ";
        $check = imap_search($oconnection2, 'FROM "'. $value . '"', SE_UID);
        if ($check) {
            $oresult["$key"] = 'x';
        } else {
            $oresult["$key"] = 'nf';
        }
    }   
} // end of foreach loop  for Outlook Search

// Begin Yahoo search
$yresult = array();
foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {
    $check = " ";
    $check = imap_search($yconnection1, 'FROM "'. $value . '"');
    if ($check) {
            $yresult["$key"] = 'v';
    } else {
        $check = " ";
        $check = imap_search($yconnection2, 'FROM "'. $value . '"', SE_UID);
        if ($check) {
            $yresult["$key"] = 'x';
        } else {
            $yresult["$key"] = 'nf';
        }
    }   
} // end of foreach loop  for Gmail Search
```

// Debbuging

```
echo print_r($gresult,1);
echo print_r($oresult,1);
echo print_r($yresult,1);
```

echo imap_last_error();

The script gives correct result for Gmail and Outlook accounts, but it gives this error when it comes to Yahoo:

**Notice**: Unknown: [SERVERBUG] SEARCH Server error - Please try again later (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

I tried to search for the answer but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If it works on Gmail and Outlook, your code is probably fine.  That's further supported by the error saying it's a server error.  Have you in fact tried again later?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to solve it since yesterday and it always show this error..

Comment: My hunch is that the problem is beyond your control, and exists with Yahoo itself; perhaps it is experiencing some problem, or is configured to always respond to these requests in this way.....oh, but I notice your first Yahoo call to `imap_search` doesn't include `SE_UID`...is that intentional?

Comment: Yahoo's server has weird server consistency issues at times.  You may need to reformulate your search, or run a NOOP before doing your search.